# put integer into 4 char array elements

Tags: c, arrays

is there any way how to put integer sized 100 000 into 4 elements of char array? If I use sprintf or itoa, array has 6 elements. I tried to use this, but it didnt work. And is there any way how to put these 4 elements back to integer?

```
char *s; 
int value = 100000; 
*((int *)s)=value;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "put"?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  If you use `sprintf` or `itoa`, your result will be the *ASCII characters* that represent that integer. The code you've shown now is going to copy the binary value as it is in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

```
int value = 100000; 
char *s; 
*((int *)s)=value;
```

dereferences uninitialized pointer `s`, which causes *undefined behavior*. You could do:

```
int value = 100000; 
char s[4]; 
*((int *)&s[0])=value;
```

just note that this stores `value` in the memory block "occupied" by charr array (at memory level) unlike `sprintf`, which would print the value in a form of string (characters representing the number).